# HDF5 linking error

Tags: c++, c++11, hdf5

When linking my `hdf5` code I get the following error. Any ideas what I have done wrong.

**The command I am using:**

> g++ -std=c++11 -m64 -DOPENFOAM_PLUS=1712 -Dlinux64 -DWM_ARCH_OPTION=64 -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32 -Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-cast -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-attributes -O3  -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -I/opt/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude -I/opt/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/src/sampling/lnInclude   -I/opt/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/src/meshTools/lnInclude  -IlnInclude -I. -I/opt/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude -I/opt/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude   -fPIC -Xlinker --add-needed -Xlinker --no-as-needed Make/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/3DIBicoFoam_2.o -L/opt/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib \
>       -lfiniteVolume -lsampling   -L/local/hulfeldl/hdf5/lib/libhdf5_hl_cpp.a     -L/local/hulfeldl/hdf5/lib/libhdf5_cpp.a    -L/local/hulfeldl/hdf5/lib/libhdf5_hl.a     -L/local/hulfeldl/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.a -lhdf5_hl_cpp -lhdf5_cpp -lhdf5_hl     -lhdf5 -lsz -lz -ldl -lm  -lOpenFOAM -ldl  \
>        -lm -o /local/hulfeldl/OpenFOAM/hulfeldl-v1712/applications/bin/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/3DIBicoFoam_2

**Error:**

```
Make/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/3DIBicoFoam_2.o: In function `main':
3DIBicoFoam_2.C:(.text.startup+0x107b): undefined reference to 
`H5::H5Location::openDataSet(std::string const&) const' 
3DIBicoFoam_2.C:(.text.startup+0x17de): undefined reference to 
`H5::H5Location::openDataSet(std::string const&) const'
3DIBicoFoam_2.C:(.text.startup+0x189e): undefined reference to 
`H5::H5Location::openDataSet(std::string const&) const'
3DIBicoFoam_2.C:(.text.startup+0x1919): undefined reference to 
`H5::H5Location::openDataSet(std::string const&) const'
3DIBicoFoam_2.C:(.text.startup+0x19d0): undefined reference to 
`H5::H5Location::openDataSet(std::string const&) const'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: How did you generate that command? It's a gynormous mess. 
`-L/local/hulfeldl/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.a` is meaning less. `-L` adds library search directories. Please remove all `-L/...a` to start with. Add one single `-L/local/hulfeldl/hdf5/lib` leave all -lhdf... in the command. And retry.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's compiling. But when I execute I get:  error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.100: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: if it is a C library,  compiler will add parameters to  function signature. May be extern "C" would resolve that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove all `-L/...a` to start with. Add one single `-L/local/hulfeldl/hdf5/lib` leave all `-lhdf...` in the command. And retry.

For runtime please run the following before you run your program.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/local/hulfeldl/hdf5/lib
```